# Getting users from Azure AD B2C: not supported for this API version

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have taken over part of a project from a colleague that uses Azure AD B2C.

At the moment we use the list of users in the [old Azure portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/) to get the authentication tokens of users, which we can then tie in with the user entries in our own database. I.e. we copy-and-paste from the columns here:

[image: Azure Portal (old) screenshot]

It would be far more sensible to do this programatically.

The article [Azure AD B2C Preview: Use the Graph API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet/) includes sample code to download. To get it running I needed these things:

```xml
<appSettings>
    <add key="b2c:Tenant" value="[Enter tenant name, e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com]" />
    <add key="b2c:ClientId" value="[Enter the client ID (a.k.a AppPrincipalId) as obtained from the Azure AD Powershell, e.g. 82692da5-a86f-44c9-9d53-2f88d52b478b]" />
    <add key="b2c:ClientSecret" value="[Enter the client secret that you generated, e.g. ONHJGaI232VenJIboyg8hmTlyNXh0Ef0brRRRNWBRfc=]" />
</appSettings>
```

I can get the Tenant and the Application ID from the new Azure Portal portal:

[image: Azure portal (new) screenshot]

and my colleague has passed me the client secret from when he made the directory.

Following the article I now compile the app and run

> B2C Get-User

But instead of the expected list of users from our Azure AD B2C directory I get the error message

> AADSTS70001: Application my-app-id is not supported for this API version.
>   Trace ID: a-guid
>   Correlation ID: another-guid
>   Timestamp: 2016-07-15 10:27:15Z

How do I programmatically get the users in my Azure AD B2C directory?

Answer (score 1):

Run the powershell commands from here to register a new service principal:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet/

This new service principal has it's own appId, and it's own client secret.

You mixed some of these (the AppId you chose is from an B2C application, not a B2C/AD Service principal)